# Improving performance of anomaly detection using dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, supervised-learning, anomaly-detection, semi-supervised-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am leveraging an isolation forest model from the scikit-learn library for anomaly detection in a time series dataset where each point in the dataset is a data frame. However, I possess additional knowledge about specific criteria that can identify non-anomalous data points. How can I integrate this knowledge with the existing model to enhance its accuracy?

Before describing please consider that I am newbie to data science so pardon the flaws. I know I can use supervised methods or hyperparameter on top of anomaly detection methods to incorporate what I asked. But I feel it will destroy the advantage of using anomaly detection over supervised learning i.e. considering each batch independent of others and taking decision based on that batch's information itself. I used anomaly detection instead of any other supervised learning method because I feel the data may evolve and the rate of false/anolamaly occurence is nearly constant over different batch; and anomaly detection being dynamic can handle such situations. If I used supervised learning method on top of anomaly detection this novelty will be lost as dense layer will consider past data and may lead to positive feedback of errors.

I am trying to find method to improve the anomaly results such that this method can guide the original algorithm based on criterias that the point which are closer to 'good rows' are not to be considered anomaly, but originality i.e. anomaly detection without this consideration also retains some weightage. This method should solely rely on current batch's knowledge.

I understand that my approach may be flawed, and I welcome any corrections and suggestions.

Edit: Based on comments I'll try to briefly explain implementation and usage. I have a process which keeps on generating new data the rate is not constant (one of the reason for opting for anomaly detection); as I am accumulating results of anomalies I donot want to find all anomalies at once but I want that if it detect the anomaly it should be an anomaly (i.e. high precision); rates are approximately two anomalies out of 900 points. I poll and wait till the process has generated atleast 900 data samples and then feed them to the isolation forest. This gives distance based score and I currently am using static threshold to point out anomaly points. Now among those samples there are some samples which I am sure are not anomaly. There are also some other samples which I am sure are not anomaly but I think if anomaly detection learns from them it might miss some actual anomalies so I want that they only subtly impact the original anomaly algo. Also I donot want the method to be static in the sense that while some data samples may be good right now but similar samples can be rightly classified to anomaly based on that time slot's other data samples; thus I am avoiding hyper parameter optimization or dnn on top of anomaly detection from supervised data.

Another question I have is will it be feasible if I put the 'good point' criteria before fitting the data frame? I think in this case the information will be lost so I haven't done it yet.

Comment: One way to interpret "anomaly detection" is "class imbalance". I choose to view it in this way. There are two generative Processes in the world, P1 + P2. For example P1 might be "customer purchased product" and P2 might be "fraudster sent a fraudulent transaction", with imbalanced rates P1 >> P2.  In this setting, AD can become a classification task, where we are asked to label "which process generated this example?" Update your question to tell us about the processes and rates involved. If you can assign probabilities, you can improve your detection rate. What have you implemented so far?

Comment: @J_H Thanks for guidance, can u look at modified question (Edit part) if should provide more information.

Comment: Sorry I was a bit vague when I said "tell us about...". Please tell us about the business domain that processes P1 and P2 are drawn from. What is P1? What is P2? It sounds like you are able to Ground Truth those two anomaly examples. (You _will_ need more data, BTW.) How does a human evaluate an example to ground truth it? // Suppose that P1 and P2 are [MoG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution#Two_normal_distributions) mixture of Gaussian processes. They have infinite support, so any "outlier" _could_ have been generated by either P1 or P2. Business domain knowledge can help!

Comment: @J_H Sorry I donot totally get what you mean by buisness domain. But I guess in my case buisness domain is spam email detection, P1 is genuine person sending mail, P2 is fraudster sending mail. About human evaluation I currently have no structured feedback mechanism but rather some more structured rules which can identify part of P1 cases and part of P2 cases with confidence. Does this helps?

Comment: Oh, so it's a ham / spam classifier. Where process P1a is "my friend contacted me", P1b is "a company I do business with and granted permission to has contacted me", and P2 is Nigerian princes and so on. Good. There is a mature literature on Spam Detection going back decades. Cite a reference and implement their technique. Tell us which one you're using. // Gathering spam is easy -- sign up with a free email provider, **do not** use the account with friends, and mention its name on sites like Reddit or X/Twitter. By definition, only P2 spammers send to its inbox.

Comment: @J_H I guess I already described implementation.

Comment: I have used Isolation Forest before. It's not obvious to me how IF would help with ham / spam classification. In _your_ dataset there's only 2 spams, but some inboxes are more than 50% spam, and some of the spams closely resemble one another, so they would be separated by very small distance. Usually vocabulary, number of messages exchanged in both directions with sender, SMTP header details, and "is this HTML / JS visible?" features are what drive a spam detector -- consult the literature. We might baseline against cosine distance on those features. In your IF AD setup I see no baseline.

Comment: @J_H Sorry I forgot to mention it's not only about spams/hams but about domains & client subnets which are actually sending them.